# Which one is better EWS API or EWS managed API?

Tags: exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

I am developing email client for exchange server  ....... I came across EWS  and EWS Managed API. Please help me understand which one I should go for ?

Comment: The EWS Managed API is a .net wrapper around EWS. So if you're in .net, go for that one. Otherwise, forget about the managed wrapper and code against EWS directly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are:

1. Using .Net and the functionality is implemented in the EWS Managed API....use the EWS Managed API.
2. Using .Net and the functionality is not implemented in the EWS Managed API....use the EWS Managed API to discover the EWS endpoint, and then code directly against EWS or use a proxy object model generator.
3. Using Java (not Android), use the EWS Java API. Note that this isn't actively updated, but you have access to the source.
4. For everything else, look to see if there are client implementations available. For example, you could evaluate [IndependentSoft's](http://www.independentsoft.de/) client implementation (this is not an endorsement, this is just me giving an option). If not, you should implement Autodiscover and the EWS client.